# How to click on the element through onclick event as per the html through Selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to fond an xpath for a link on a web page.
The HTML for the link looks like this:

```
<td style="width: 50%; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle">
    <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1"  
    alt="Add Controller" src="../Images/AddRecord.gif">
        <a onclick="return ShowInsertController(2);" href="#">link</a>
</td>
```

Some how i am not able to get the correct xpath.
I have tried the following ways:

```
xpath = //img[@id  ='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1']/a -->Didnt work

xpath = //td[contains(@onclick, 'return ShowInsertController(2);')] --> Didnt work

xpath = //img[@id  ='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1']/a[1] -->Didnt work
```

I cannot use linktext as web app is customizable in other languages.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how come I can get -1 vote when I am formatting the code. People are really fast to give -1 Thank you really pro active user @Shivam Mishra

Comment: What is the text between <a> and </a>

Comment: <a onclick="return ShowInsertController(2);" href="#">link</a>

Comment: It seems in your page you have other same types of element and id's are dynamic. can you provide some more HTML so someone help you out or try @DebanjanB 's solution

Comment: Found the solution and my mistake. I ended up using another upper table id and combined with <a> and the xpath that worked perfect for me is //table[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_TopPager']//td//a[1]
Thnx @cruisepandey and@NarendraR for paying positive attention to my question.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to `click()` on the *link* with text as **link** through an *xpath* and `onclick()` event you can use either of the following solutions:

- `xpath 1`:

  ```
  //td/a[@onclick=\"return ShowInsertController(2);\"]
  ```
- `xpath 2`:

  ```
  //td/img[@alt='Add Controller' and contains(@src,'AddRecord')]//following::a[@onclick=\"return ShowInsertController(2);\"]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the img and anchor tag are siblings,
have you tried the following code below?

`//img[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1']/following-sibling::node()[@onclick = 'return ShowInsertController(2);']`

OR

`//a[@onclick = 'return ShowInsertController(2);']/preceding-sibling::node()[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1']`

Comment: Thnx @Money Coder. First xpath works perfect for me.

Comment: Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st and 3rd xpaths won't work because you are trying to find `<a>` elements which are *child* of the `<img>` element. If you type:

```
//img[whatever]/a
```

To the code it means, search for `<a>` elements which is the first child of the `<img>` element of `whatever` locator. Read [online tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) for better understanding of how xpaths work.

Coming to the second xpath you tried, you are trying to locate a `<td>` element with the help of `onclick` attribute. Its the `<a>` element which has that and not the `<td>` element. So even that is incorrect.

**Solution:**

In your case, `<a>` is the sibling of your `<img>` element, meaning it is placed on the same node hierarchy next (and not under) your `<img>` element. So you should use this xpath instead:

```
//img[@id  ='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1']/following-sibling::a
```

@cruisepandey is correct in pointing out that the id `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1` could be dynamic so a more stable locator should be:

```
//img/following-sibling::a[contains(text(),'link')]
```

or, the ones @Debanjan provided.

Comment: The image id looks quite dynamic, may be changed at any point of time.

Comment: @cruisepandey correct, thanks for pointing out. Edited my answer.

Comment: @Shivam Mishra  the id ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_AddRecord1  is not dynamic. And for the second option you suggested I cannot use it because my application supports multiple language (I mentioned in my initial que) and if I hard code the 'link' in english then script will fail when I will execute it in other language.

Comment: @reena ok, got your point. But, the first one is suitable for you, right?